# WordPress: BuddyPress: Allow only one email domain to register

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

In the BuddyPress, I want to allow register and log in using only one email domain. For instance, xxx@myemaildomain.com restore all will be disallowed.

I have checked in the BuddyPress source and found that BuddyPress is using `bp_core_validate_user_signup( $user_name, $user_email )` for sign up that has a filter

```
return apply_filters( 'bp_core_validate_user_signup', $result );
```

So I have tried to use the filter to modify the `user_email` filed as in the code below. But it is not working.

```
function wf_validate_email_domain($result)
{

    $email = $result[ 'user_email' ];

    // make sure we've got a valid email
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // split on @ and return last value of array (the domain)
        $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));

        if ($domain != 'mydomain.com') {
            $result[ 'user_email' ] = '';
        }
    }

    return $result;

}

add_filter('bp_core_validate_user_signup', 'wf_validate_email_domain', 9999);
```

> **Question:**
>
> How can I validate email so it allows to register and login only from
>   one specific email domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$result` should contain an `errors` field, according to the documentation:
https://www.buddyboss.com/resources/reference/functions/bp_core_validate_user_signup/

Therefore, you should add an error instead of setting the mail address to an empty string like so:

```
function wf_validate_email_domain($result)
{
    $allowed_domain = 'apolloblake.com';
    $email = $result[ 'user_email' ];

    // make sure we've got a valid email
    if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // split on @ and return last value of array (the domain)
        $domain = array_pop(explode('@', $email));

        if ($domain != $allowed_domain) {
            $result[ 'errors' ]->add( 'user_email', 
            "You may only register with mail addresses on @${allowed_domain}." );
        }
    }

    return $result;

}
```

You may have to make this message multilingual, but that depends on your WP setup.

Comment: I see. let me try this too. BTW, I found another solution using action. But I prefer using a filter. I will try your code and see which works better. Thanks